# NSPanel has black background and text is invisible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, screensaver, nspanel

I'm trying to make a configure sheet appear for a `ScreenSaverView` subclass. After a long battle with Xcode, I'm finally getting the configure sheet to appear when "Screen Saver Options" is clicked in System Preferences (and my screen saver is selected), and the sheet behaves normally with one exception: the background is black, rendering text invisible (see image).[image: Black background on configure sheet.]

This occurs regardless of whether the sheet is an `NSPanel` or `NSWindow` class, and whether the panel is a Regular Panel, Utility Panel, or HUD Panel. The only thing I can seem to do is change is the alpha value of the panel, which as expected makes everything more transparent (but the text is still not visible). Interestingly, calling `setOpaque` or `setBackgroundColor` on the `NSPanel` or `NSWindow` don't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out why it's showing up as black, we'd really need to see code for how you're creating the window.

I just did a quick test project and it seems to work OK here. IMO, the easiest solution for creating the window to return in the `configureSheet` method is to use an `NSWindowController` subclass to load a nib file in which you've configured the window ahead of time.

So in your `ScreenSaverView` subclass, you'd define an interface something like the following:

```
@interface MDScreenSaverFinaglerView : ScreenSaverView {
    MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController        *optionsWindowController;

    NSInteger                                    screenSaverViewMode;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController
                                             *optionsWindowController;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger screenSaverViewMode;

@end
```

Your implementation would then look like this for the `configureSheet` method:

```
- (NSWindow *)configureSheet {
    if (optionsWindowController == nil) {
        optionsWindowController = [[MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController alloc]
                                                  initWithScreenSaverView:self];
    }
    return optionsWindowController.window;
}
```

Basically, you check to see if the `optionsWindowController` instance exists, creating it if necessary, then return its `window`.

The interface for the custom `NSWindowController` subclass would look like the following:

```
@interface MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController : NSWindowController {
    IBOutlet NSMatrix                *optionsMatrix;

    MDScreenSaverFinaglerView        *screenSaverView;    // non-retained/weak reference
}

- (id)initWithScreenSaverView:(MDScreenSaverFinaglerView *)aView;

@property (nonatomic, assign) MDScreenSaverFinaglerView *screenSaverView;

- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender;

@end
```

There's a `screenSaverView` property which will allow communication back with the `ScreenSaverView` subclass once the user has clicked the OK button.

The nib file for the `MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController` class (named "MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController.xib") is set up like shown below:

[image]

The implementation of the `MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController` looks like the following:

```
@implementation MDScreenSaverOptionsWindowController

@synthesize screenSaverView;

- (id)initWithScreenSaverView:(MDScreenSaverFinaglerView *)aView {
    NSParameterAssert(aView != nil);
    if ((self = [super initWithWindowNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class])])) {
        self.screenSaverView = aView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [optionsMatrix selectCellWithTag:screenSaverView.screenSaverViewMode];
}

- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender {
    NSInteger viewMode = [optionsMatrix selectedTag];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber
                  numberWithInteger:viewMode] forKey:MDScreenSaverViewModeKey];
    screenSaverView.screenSaverViewMode = viewMode;
    [NSApp endSheet:self.window];
}
@end
```

The end result:

[image]

Sample project: [ScreenSaverFinagler.zip](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/ScreenSaverFinagler.zip)